# QuickSort algorithm experiencing problems

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am not sure what is wrong with my code but at line 30 when the recursion starts my program breaks and only prints out the unsorted array and the quickSort algorithm never finishes.  If anyone has any clue as to why this program is not working correctly please let me know.  Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

void quickSort(int qarray[], int l, int r){

    int i = l, j = r;
    int temp;
    int pivot = qarray[(l+r)]/2;

    //partitioning
    while(i<=j){
        while(qarray[i]< pivot)
            i++;
        while(qarray[j] > pivot)
            j--;
        if(i<=j){

            temp = qarray[i];
            qarray[i] = qarray[j];
            qarray[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;

        }
      }
    //Recursion of the quicksort algorithm
    if(l < j){

        quickSort(qarray,l,j);

    }
    if(i < r){

        quickSort(qarray,i,r);

    }

}

int main(){

    clock_t tStart = clock();

    int myArray[26] ={4,2,5,6,1,3,17,14,67,45,32,66,88,
                   78,69,92,93,21,25,23,71,61,59,60,30,79}; 

    for(int i=0;i < 26;i++){

        cout << "Unsorted: " << myArray[i] << endl;
    }


    quickSort(myArray,0,25);

    for(int i=0;i < 26;i++){

        cout << "Sorted: " << myArray[i] << endl;
    }


    double seconds = clock() / double(CLK_TCK);
    cout << "This program has been running for " << seconds << " seconds." << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you step through it with a debugger?

Comment: At first glance, the partition appears incorrect for handling the pivot, though I'm not certain.  Partition should continue while `i<j`, not `i<=j`, swapping when indexes are equal isn't wrong per-se, just slower.

Comment: -1 *Posts wall of code* Why no worky?

Comment: I dunno why people are down voting my question....  Thanks to Rost he saw my error and the program now works.

Comment: A quick test shows infinite recursion: http://ideone.com/5H8CG  Would have been good of you to mention that to us.

Comment: +1 for the code being a simple, nearly self-contained example that exhibits the problem. You just need a `#include <cstdlib>` for the `system` call; besides that, it's compilable after a simple copy-paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error in this line (at least): `int pivot = qarray[(l+r)]/2;`

Must be `int pivot = qarray[(l + r) / 2];`

There is no sense to divide element of array by 2. Pivot is middle element of range which index is `(l + r) / 2`.

Comment: There is no sense to divide **element** of array by 2. pivot is middle element of range which index is (l+r)/2.

Comment: Thank you sir that did fix the problem...i did not realize had made that error.  Thank you very much